# SAS EG running wrong file

Tags: sas, data-science, enterprise-guide

I've been having a weird problem. Every so often, I'll run a program in SAS EG that's part of a project, and SAS EG will, for reasons unclear to me, run a different file in that project, instead of the one I told it to run. As in, I'll open up the file I want, press "run", and then come back to SAS EG an hour later when it's done running, only to look at the log, results, and output and be very confused, because they're all very obviously from a different file in the same project (even though I'm reading the file I intended to run). What could be going on here, and how do I avoid it in the future?

Thanks?